# Combing numbers but not adding them in PHP

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm trying to do a server-side validation of the date chosen by user and the current date and here's what I have:

```
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$dateval = $year + $month + $day;

if ($dateval - $today < 0) {
$datepassed = 'no';
}
else {
$datepassed = 'yes';    
}
```

Now as far as I know, everything is working flawlessly except the fact that the $dateval variable just adds up all the numbers instead of putting them together to form the date chosen by the user. for example 20110719 returns 2037. How can I make a veriable that combines the numbers without adding them? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're concatenating strings, you should be using the concatenation operator, `.`:

```
$dateval = $year . $month . $day;
```

Otherwise, PHP will be clever and [convert your strings to integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), a consequence of weak typing as implemented by the PHP language.

Comment: Wow. I'm such a noob. Too much JavaScripting does that to you.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to concatenate them as strings, use the dot (.)

```
$dateval = $year . $month . $day;
```

however, since you are working with dates, consider using the [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function

```
$dateval = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP concatination uses `.` not `+`. The plus sign is how JavaScript (and probably other languages) concatenate strings.

```
$dateval = $year . $month . $day;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace the `+` (add) with `.` (concatenate).

```
$dateval = $year.$month.$day;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them as **a string**. A **dot operator** does that.

Also make sure that format of $dateval is similar to the format of $today (i.e. include dashes if needed):

```
$dateval = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

Answer (score 1):

They must be strings and a `.` used.